# Dropdown list populating too many elements in datasheet view — SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, view

I have a standard list in SharePoint, one column of which is of type `Person` or `Group`.

When I'm viewing the list from a standard view, the dropdown filter for that column lists, as expected, only those people who are already listed as a value for at least one row.

However, when I view the list from a datasheet view, the dropdown filter lists all of the groups and users on the entire site instead of just those users who are values on the list.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to configure the datasheet-view dropdown list to only show those users that are listed in a field?